# Kubuntu Audio Volume too low for some applications

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, kde

Whenever I start my applications, they begin to run with a fixed volume unequal to "100%", so I need to open the AUDIO VOLUME options in order to increase what I need. So it looks like those values were saved somewhere.

I prefer to have every application at 100% and then I'll use the General Volume or buttons as needed for my purpose.

i.e. Firefox starts at 40% and Zoom playStream at 59% every time, that annoys me.
[image]

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution in the meantime?  I have the same issue with Zoom (always starts at 51%) which is pretty annoying.